# i can't find the the tables of jpa entities in mysqlworkbench

Tags: spring-data-jpa, mysql-workbench

i created a database called demo in mysqlworkbench and i created 2 jpa entities user and role and when i run the spring boot application i don't get an error but i don't see the tables created also in the database

heres the jpa entities

```
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YRpA.png)
```

and heres the applicationproperties file
[enter image description here]   (https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLAQ8.png)

and the dependicies

```
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPe9i.png)
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pogSz.png)
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzW5I.png)
```

after i run the program i get this outpout in the console
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkqSH.png)